# Flutter Filter List with multiple Level Params

Tags: list, flutter, filter, parameters

I am a beginner in flutter . I have a list view where i am getting data from server which is working fine. The problem is i want to filter the list based on multiple custom params The attachment are below

[List data from server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yEcF.png)

this is working fine now I want to filter this list based on this image below:
[Filter Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRTiz.png)

Please help me Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi! You can use where method of List - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html
For more detailed answer please provide code of list item type

Comment: @Mol0ko Thanks for the Support i will follow this and will let you know with code soon